# Unit testing and assert result

Tags: c#

I have Video Service class as follows:

```
public class VideoService
{
    private IFileReader _fileReader;
    private IVideoRepository _repository;
    public string _videoPath;

    public VideoService(IFileReader fileReader, IVideoRepository repository)
    {
        _fileReader = fileReader;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string ReadVideoTitle()
    {
        var str = _fileReader.Read(_videoPath);
        if (str == "")
        {
            return "";
        }
            else
        {
            return "b";
        }        
    }
}
```

then there is IFileReader and FileReader as below:

```
   public interface IFileReader
    {
        string Read(string path);
    }

    public class FileReader : IFileReader
    {
        public string Read(string path)
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(path);
        }
    }
```

Now i have my unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class VideoServiceTests
{
    private VideoService _videoService;
    private Mock<IFileReader> _fileReader;
    private Mock<IVideoRepository> _repository;
    private string _videoPath;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _fileReader = new Mock<IFileReader>();
        _repository = new Mock<IVideoRepository>();
        _videoPath = @"test.txt";
        _videoService = new VideoService(_fileReader.Object, _repository.Object);
        }

[Test]
     public void ReadVideoTitle_EmptyFile_ReturnError()
     {
        _fileReader.Setup(fr => fr.Read(_videoPath)).Returns("");
        var result = _videoService.ReadVideoTitle();
        Assert.That(result, Does.Contain("").IgnoreCase);
}
```

My problem is and what i am not understanding. When i do `_fileReader.Setup ..`
My understanding is it is a fake reader and not `FileReader class` right?, therefore when i say put whatever in `Read` parameter like: `test.txt` then i say i am expecting `Returns ""`. In Assert i am comparing it to what i get from `ReadVideoTitle`. However what is the sense of Assert here? Since `_fileReader` is just interface and not real class it will not really look and try to read fake `test.txt` file and look for output. Therefore first question why i always get `test Success` whatever i put in `_fileReader.Setup`. How it checks whether is `Success`? Shouldn'e it be just Vlaidate() if Read was really called, since it's nt really testing values? Can anyone be so kind and explain me how current example test works and what is really testing because so far i am lost.

Comment: A non-null string always contains the empty string. You should test whether it is **equal** to an empty string. `IgnoreCase` is irrelevant when testing against an empty string.

Comment: can you explain whether when i do Setup of my moc is it really setting _videoPath and says that this filesreader's return value is "" what set in Returns? Means in ReadVideoTitle here: var str = _fileReader.Read(_videoPath); is it really taken from what i setup in Setup() ?

Comment: My understanding is that **if** `.Read(..)` is callled with `_videoPath` **then** it will return `""`, not that it will be called with it. The real parameter is passed by your `VideoService` implementation when calling `Read`. (Note: I'm used to NSubsitute, so it might be different here)